# Sorting a list of objects in java

Tags: java, collections

I want to sort this list of `Emp` objects in ascending order based on the `marks` field.

```
List<Emp> emp= new ArrayList<Emp>();

public class Emp implements Serializable {
    private String empname;
    private String section;
    private int empId;
    private int marks;
    ...
```

Comment: So what did you try? What is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302005/any-utility-method-to-sort-java-util-list-containing-pojos-of-the-kind-of-apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main ways of supporting object comparisons in Java.

You can have your class implement the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, which is acceptable when your objects have a natural ordering that you're relying on (for example, alphabetical ordering for strings). This requires classes to implement a `compareTo` method which defines the comparison rule between instances.

The standard alternative is to instantiate a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for your class, and specify the comparison rule in a `compare` method.

In your case, the latter option seems more appropriate. The mechanics of the `compare` method are fairly simple: it takes two instances of your class, returns a negative value if the first is "less than" the second, a positive number if it is "greater", and 0 if they are "equal". For integer-based comparisons, like comparing by `marks`, the quick trick is to return the difference of the numbers.

Once you have your `Comparator` defined, sorting is as simple as invoking the [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) method, opting for the method signature which takes a `List` and a specified `Comparator`.

```
List<Emp> emps = new ArrayList<Emp>();
// populate list...

Comparator<Emp> empComparator = new Comparator<Emp>() {
    public int compare(Emp e1, Emp e2) {
        return e2.getMarks() - e2.getMarks();
    }
};

Collections.sort(emps, empComparator);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to write a comparator, otherwise the Sort method assumes which fields you want use when sorting.

```
 Collections.sort(emp, new Comparator<Emp>() { public int compare(Emp one, Emp two) {
       return one.marks.compareTo(two.marks);
  });
```

In my example i treated the field marks as public, replace one.marks with a getter if you so choose.

Also since you're using ints which do not have a compareTo, do like so:

```
     Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Emp>() {
       public int compare(Emp one, Emp two) {
           int cmp = one.getMarks() > two.getMarks() ? +1 : one.getMarks() < two.getMarks() ? -1 : 0;
           return cmp;
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comparator object to sort.

```
Collections.sort();
```

does the sorting.

This will work with your List. The method to be used is compareTo.

```
    if (list.size() > 0) {
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Emp>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final Emp object1, final Emp object2) {
            return object1.getMarks().compareTo(object2.getMarks());
        }
       } );
   }
```